# Code Coverage with SonarQube integrated with Tomcat without Maven

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco

I ran code coverage with jacoco(using javaagent)integrating it in startup.bat of tomcat and got jacoco.exec. I also got a html report for that.

Now, I want code coverage in sonarqube. I ran sonar-scanner and got all the details except "Code-coverage".

Is there a way to have Code-Coverage without updating the pom.xml? Or if I could have code-coverage in sonarqube using jacoco.exec?

Comment: Can you post more details, like the code you've tried so far?
Can you post the html report?

Comment: Using sonar-scanner, you can specify where your generated jacoco.exex file is located. Sonarqube will then use the results generated by Jacoco.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You just have to add `sonar.jacoco.reportPaths` parameter.

Examples:

- SonarQube Scanner + `sonar-project.properties`:

  ```
  sonar.jacoco.reportPaths=/path/jacoco.exec,/path/another/jacoco.exec
  ```
- Gradle:

  ```
  sonarqube {
      properties {
          property "sonar.jacoco.reportPaths", "/path/jacoco.exec,/path/another/jacoco.exec"
      }
  }
  ```
- Maven:

  ```
  mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.jacoco.reportPaths=/path/jacoco.exec,/path/another/jacoco.exec
  ```

Read more here: [Java Unit Tests and Coverage Results Import](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+Unit+Tests+and+Coverage+Results+Import)

Comment: I've updated the post. Now it shows how to do it with Sonar Scanner, Gradle and Maven.